# broken indentation formatting when if/else chain is over 100 lines in length - visual studio 2017 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, if-statement, formatting, indentation

While using Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.35
I noticed that for functions with long if/else chains the indentation would break at some point. After some experimentation I was able to figure out why; when the if/else chain is over 100 lines in length (from the first if() line) the formatting breaks.

//under 100 lines with expected behavior

```
void test()
{
    int x = 10;
    if(x == 10)
    {
        x = 11; 
    }
    else //when you press enter twice the closing bracket is in the correct position
    {
        x = 12;
    }
}
```

//>= 100 lines

```
void test()
{
    int x = 10;
    if(x == 10)
    {
        x = 11;
        x = 11;
        ... repeat 95 more times (97 in total)
    }
    else //when you press enter twice the formatting breaks
    {
    x=12;
}
}
```

After this happens all new lines of code are misaligned by 1 tab which gets really annoying. The example I gave is unrealistic but easy to reproduce, in a real scenario just reaching 100+ lines cumulatively (not just in a single block) causes the same behavior. I was wondering if this is a bug or if there is some setting I can adjust or plugin I can install to get the correct behavior. I'm aware that refactoring the code by moving the block code into separate functions to reduce the overall length is an option too, but this is not always the most desirable solution. I was going to report this on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/ as well, but I'm not sure if 2017 is still supported.

Also just to reiterate, the question is: Is this a bug or is there some setting I can adjust or plugin I can install to get the correct behavior.

Comment: update to the latest version, if that doesn't fix it report it to MS. Having 100 lines inside a single function is pretty unreadable, having 100 lines in a single if statement is even worse. Refactor your code into multiple functions, if they're declared inline it should generally optimise to the same assembly and make your code much more readable and maintainable

Comment: 2019 has the same issue

Comment: *The example I gave is unrealistic but easy to reproduce, in a real scenario just reaching 100+ lines cumulatively* -- The MS team is currently pushing out updates to 2019 on a regular basis.  Report the issue to them, since you can duplicate it easily.

Comment: not the best solution but you could use an `inline` function?

Comment: I reported this issue to the MS team. According to them this is a known issue that can also be triggered by other actions such as declaring an enum that spans over 100 lines. Hopefully they get around to fixing soon.

Answer (score 0):

After reporting this issue to the Microsoft team it was noted that this is a known issue. This confirms that it is indeed a bug and not something settings related.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Inconsistent-auto-tabulation-behavior-wh/1429071

While looking through some other reports that were also flagged as duplicates I found this partial solution for VS 2019.

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2019-and-C:-Indenting-on/986698

> The only way I’ve found to stop this in the Options is to change the
> Tabs->Indent from Smart to Block. But unfortunately this also disables
> other options that I do want, such as formatting a section when I type
> “}” or “;”.